# Chrome Extension - override .js file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is a website that has a certain bug in the JS file. The JS file is only being referenced in one place:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/r/js/no-closure/dialogs.js?v=2"></script>
```

I've downloaded the JS file and fixed the bug. Is there any way I can, via a chrome extension, override the `/r/js/no-closure/dialogs.js` with my `dialogs_fixed.js`?

I've tried (in `background.js`):

```
var script = $('[src*="dialogs.js"]');
script.attr("src", "dialogs_patch.js");
```

No luck.

Comment: Where you able to fix the issue? If yes could you share your solution?

Answer (score 7):

You dont need to use the experimental webRequest for this, you could just use the beforeload event.
Something like this should work....

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(pattern) {
    var d = this.length - pattern.length;
    return d >= 0 && this.lastIndexOf(pattern) === d;
};

document.addEventListener('beforeload', function(event) {
if (event.url.endsWith("/r/js/no-closure/dialogs.js?v=2")){event.srcElement.src=chrome.extension.getURL("dialogs.js");}
}, true);
```

..put that in a content script targeting the page your interested in.
And make sure you make this content script load before the page does by adding...

```
"run_at" : "document_start"
```

...to your content scripts field....

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

**EDIT**
Altho it should be noted that as of Chrome 17 the web request api is no longer experimental and is a great way to do redirects.

Comment: Note that "beforeload" event is only supported by Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari): https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW9 (watch "Blocking Unwanted Content")

Comment: There is an alternative for Firefox: http://webmynd.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/equivalent-to-beforeload-event-for-firefox-extensions/

Comment: Edit: the "beforeload" event was removed from chrome :( https://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/issues/detail?id=6596

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to block it with experimental `webRequest` api:

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
    return {cancel: true}; 
}, {urls: ["http://www.example.com/r/js/no-closure/dialogs.js"]}, ["blocking"]);
```

Comment: Could you please update your answer, since it's no longer experimental?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the attribute in the source code, another approach could be to intercept the request for the javascript file and return your new file.

You can do this using the Redirect Rule in Requestly as follows:

1. Open the network tab in chrome dev tools and search for the request for this exact file. Copy the source URL of the request.
2. Install the Requestly extension. Go to app.requestly.io and create a new redirect rule
3. Give the rule a name and paste the URL that you previously copied as the Request URL
4. Run a local server that serves your fixed javascript file and enter the local endpoint next to **Redirect To**

[image: redirect rule]

If you do not want to setup a local server, Requestly lets you easily build endpoints to serve files or even setup  and provides you an endpoint that you can use at **step 4**

To serve your file using Requestly mocks

1. Click on **Mock Files** in side pannel
2. Click on **Create New Mock** and select **Mock JS**
3. Give it a name, paste the contents of your "fixed" javascript file and create the mock.

You can now either copy the endpoint or click on **Pick from Mock Server** while building the rule