# While making a chrome extension, replace script called by website with my own script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building an extension for Google Chrome and for a website I want to be able to replace a script called by a website with my own script.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension to modify page's script includes and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075620/chrome-extension-to-modify-pages-script-includes-and-js)