# Accessing the console log commands via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, console

I'm looking to override the existing console commands via my Chrome extension - the reason for this is I wish to record the console logs for a specific site.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to update the DOM, this is what i've tried so far:

```
// Run functions on page change
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    // TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
    s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('core/js/app/console.js');
    s.onload = function() {
        this.remove();
    };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
});
```

console.js

```
// Replace functionality of console log
console.defaultLog = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function(){
    console.defaultLog.apply(console, arguments);
    console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
};

// Replace functionality of console error
console.defaultError = console.error.bind(console);
console.errors = [];
console.error = function(){
    console.defaultError.apply(console, arguments);
    console.errors.push(Array.from(arguments));
};

// Replace functionality of console warn
console.defaultWarn = console.warn.bind(console);
console.warns = [];
console.warn = function(){
    console.defaultWarn.apply(console, arguments);
    console.warns.push(Array.from(arguments));
};

// Replace functionality of console debug
console.defaultDebug = console.debug.bind(console);
console.debugs = [];
console.debug = function(){
    console.defaultDebug.apply(console, arguments);
    console.debugs.push(Array.from(arguments));
};
```

The script runs successfully with an alert().

The goal for me is to access console.logs - but its undefined which means I haven't gotten access to the DOM, despite injecting a script.

If not possible, even a third party integration would be helpful i.e. Java or C?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Look here: [How to read from Chrome's console in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846113/5792509)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076783/12184135) and I think Tampermonkey injects a script with the immediate function that you add in the Tampermonkey Chrome extension page, I found something similar in extensions like Wappalyzer, and looks good and safe, you could use [WebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to inject to your website the new "polyfill" before the page is fully loaded as the post says.

Here the example of [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg) that I mentioned before, this is the JS load in StackOverflow with Wappalyzer using the code injection, I didn't test it with Tampermonkey yet

[image]

**EDIT**

Checking Wappalyzer, how to inject the code is the easy part, you can use ([Wappalyzer github example](https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/476083fb30e0b416ee5b34ab41ade26b96b9ea53/src/drivers/webextension/js/content.js#L122)):

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.setAttribute('src', chrome.extension.getURL('js/inject.js'))
```

This probably will not fix your problem, this code is executed after all the content was loaded in the DOM. But, you can find how to fix that problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19192010/12184135)

I'll suggest to use onCommitted event ([doc1](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted)/[doc2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCommitted))

Using the mozilla.org example you will have something like

```
 const filter = {
  url: //website to track logs
  [
    {hostContains: "example.com"},
    {hostPrefix: "developer"}
  ]
}

function logOnCommitted(details) {
  //Inject Script on webpage
}

browser.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(logOnCommitted, filter);
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track :) https://github.com/AliasIO/wappalyzer/blob/master/src/drivers/webextension/manifest.json

Update it with code showing how the JS is injected an ill give you the bounty <3

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth trying to redefine the entire console object:

```js
const saved = window.console
window.console = {...saved, log: function(...args){ saved.log("Hello", ...args) }}
```

But it's probably impossible, because content scripts live in an isolated world:

> Isolated worlds do not allow for content scripts, the extension, and the web page to access any variables or functions created by the others. This also gives content scripts the ability to enable functionality that should not be accessible to the web page.

Although in [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) this script works.

I believe Tampermonkey handles this by knowing the subtleties and tracking changes in the extensions host's protection mechanism.

BTW, for small tasks, there is a decent alternative to chrome extensions in the form of [code snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/sources?utm_source=devtools&utm_campaign=2018Q1#snippets).

Comment: Hi @Spatz , thats really interesting - do you know how it would work on tamper monkey (a Chrome plugin)? That would be very interesting to know. I.e. how do they inject themselves into the DOM? :)

Comment: Just an FYI, i'd love to give this question the bounty if:
- You clarify how Tampermonkey is able to get access to console / update it as a Chrome extension. I believe if you discover this it would enable me to find a way to make my extension access it to.